# Searching linked lists from file

Tags: c, enums, linked-list, file-handling

I need with understanding of the following problem:

Given a linked list

```
typedef struct  
{
    int i;
    void * next;
    flag fg; 
}node;
```

where `flag` is the enumeration

```
typedef enum 
{
    in_file,
    in_memory
}flag;
```

where `in_file` means that list node is in a file, and `in_memory` that list node is not in a file (`next` points to a string which is the name of a file).

Given a function `node* loadList(char* file_name)` that reads the list from a file and returns the first list node.

Write a function `char* exists(node* list,int value,int* isInList)` that checks if some `value` exists in the list and returns the pointer of the file name in which the value is found.

File contains of more than one list.
While reading lists from file, rewrite the pointer `next` and type `flag` from the existing list.

**Question**: How to rewrite the pointer `next` and type `flag` from the  list?

How to use the enumeration type `flag` for searching the file?

Answer (score 1):

(Edit note: Ok, with the edited question, this is more like a comment and not actually answer to the question, but I'll leave it here anyway...)

You should probably use union instead of a void pointer:

```
struct list_node 
{
    int i;
    union {
        struct list_node *node;
        const char *filename;
    } next;
    flag fg; 
} ;
```

Then you would have code like

```
switch(node->fg) 
case in_memory:
    ....node->next.node->.....;
    break;
case in_file:
    ....node->next.filename....;
    break;
}
```